# Trouble formatting namenode in hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I'm following some instructions from a course on udemy and have successfully formatted hdfs once. Now I tried to go back and follow the steps again and am getting the following error:

```
$ hadoop namenode -­format
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

15/01/16 22:16:15 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = lucid64/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [­format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r     1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.6.0_33
************************************************************/
Usage: java NameNode [-format [-force ] [-nonInteractive]] | [-upgrade] | [-rollback] | [-finalize] | [-importCheckpoint] | [-recover [ -force ] ]
 15/01/16 22:16:15 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at lucid64/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

It doesn't look like anything is really even starting and I do not get a stack trace or meaningful (to me) error.

Comment: Can you start the Namenode and then run the command jps and post the output. If the namenode does not start and stay started make sure your IP address did not change if your using DHCP

Comment: Thank you @apesa it looks like it was actually an ownership issue. It is resolved now.